# How to delay an action called by an apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email

Here's my use-case :

I want Salesforce to automatically fire an email when a field is changed in the User Object. 
So I'm using an Apex Trigger to do that.

The only problem is that I want the email to be sent 24 hours after the field has changed and I'm struggling to find a way to do so...

Is there a way to delay an action called by an apex trigger ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried using time-dependent workflows?
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3):

While you *can* do this from a trigger, it's a much more natural use case for Process Builder or Workflow Rules using a time-delayed action, where you don't have to do any extra work to get that functionality.

To directly answer your question, yes, there is a way to do this in Apex (multiple ways, actually). One option would be to have my trigger accumulate a Set of User Ids that need to have the email sent, and then enqueue a delayed Batch class using `System.scheduleBatch()`. Another would be to have the trigger populate a Date field on the User with the date this qualifying change is made, and schedule a class to run every day that would query for User records whose Date field is equal to yesterday and send those emails. (That wouldn't necessarily get you exactly 24 hours, though).

But again, a more natural idiom is probably to just set up a Process Builder whose criteria look for the change you're interested in and use a time-delayed action to send your email.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll look into process builder and time delayed actions as you say

Comment: Obviously, not using Apex Code means that you'll have to live with the limits of what the platform supports for the email. Complicated emails that are generated using multiple queries/complex logic/etc might not be directly possible without dipping back in to Apex Code.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems to be achieved best by using:

- Process Builder with a Scheduled Action

or

- Workflow with Time-Dependent Workflow Actions.

Give it a try, it should be a straightforward solution to apply for your use case.